# How to determine whether a transformer is dead

Tags: transformer, troubleshooting, appliances

My range hood broke, so I took it apart. I confirmed that 125V is arriving at the control board, which is connected to a fuse which is good, which is connected to a transformer. My voltmeter (AC mode) measures 125 VAC on the primary side, and zero volts on the secondary side. With everything powered down my ohm-meter measures open-circuit on the primary side, and 5.6 ohms on the secondary side. I think this means the transformer is dead. Questions:

- Is there an alternative explanation for these measurements in which the transformer is not dead?
- Any other tests I should perform on the transformer?
- How might I go about purchasing a replacement part, or at-least something that has the correct winding ratio, voltage rating, and power rating? (any other params that matter?) It is marked 'TL018   835' - see photo below.

[image]

thanks

tom

Comment: Performing a continuity test on either of the windings should not give an open circuit. If is shows OL or something, then the transformer is faulty.

Comment: Do you know what voltage is required on the secondary side? And what current?
If your primary winding is OL, it is most likely totaled.